# windows 8 app: rating control within list view templazte

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to create a windows 8 app that displays a list of whatever Information in a `WinJS.UI.ListView` element. I have created a list view and an item template for it and everything works so far, but now I want to display a rating control (disabled, so that it shows average rating but users can't rate in the list view item) in each item with an average rating from my data.
I tried

```
<div data-win-options="{disabled: true}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Rating" data-win-bind="averageRating: rating"></div>
```

But it doesn't show an average rating.
What value should i use for `data-win-bind` for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference it from winControl, since it is a property of the winControl, not the html element

```
  data-win-bind="{winControl.averageRating: rating }
```